# Google Speech API speech to text only printing one word

Tags: google-speech-to-text-api

I'm working on a project and in my following code
when I press run it worke for just one word it doesn't write all my speech

My code:

[image]

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Can you add more details here like code and error?

Comment: no I didn't get any error

Comment: I added a link for my code it's an image of the code